# What does the Facebook Ads API link_click metric indicate in adcampaignstats

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

I would love to get a definitive answer or a glossary that defines the data returned from the Facebook ads api adcampaignstats.  Specifically the difference between the actions and inline_actions.  Below is the result for a dark post, and I like to know what the "link_click" metric in actions and inline_actions actually counts.  i.e. Does this tell me that in total the campaign had 342 links clicked, or does "link_click" in "actions" and "inline_actions" indicate something else?

act_{ad_account_id}/adcampaignstats?campaign_ids=[123456]
{
    "is_completed": false, 
    "social_unique_clicks": 0, 
    "topline_id": 0, 
    "unique_impressions": 0, 
    "start_time": null, 
    "campaign_id": 123456, 
    "actions": {
        "offsite_conversion.registration": 14, 
        "post_like": 2, 
        "like": 5, 
        "photo_view": 1, 
        "link_click": 180
    }, 
    "clicks": 301, 
    "inline_actions": {
        "comment": 0, 
        "video_play": 0, 
        "title_clicks": 0, 
        "like": 10, 
        "rsvp_maybe": 0, 
        "post_like": 13, 
        "photo_view": 0, 
        "rsvp_yes": 0, 
        "link_click": 162, 
        "question_vote": 0
    }, 
}

Answer (score 0):

Link clicks relate to page post ads that contain a link and is the action of the user clicking off site via the link.